# How can I install `SQL Server PowerPivot For SharePoint` for `SharePoint 2013`?

Tags: powerpivot, sql-server-2012

I have `SharePoint 2013` and `SQL Servere 2012 SP1` in my serever.

I want install `SQL Server PowerPivot For Sharepoint`.

I run SetUp of SQL Server 2012 SP1 and in `Setup Role` I Select `SQL Server PowerPivot For Sharepoint` but I am force to use `SharePoint 2010`.

[image]

How can I install `SQL Server PowerPivot For SharePoint` for `SharePoint 2013` ?

I see [This Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219067.aspx) and I see that in this page we can install `SQL Server PowerPivot For SharePoint` with out considering SharePoint version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check this guide: may help you
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/querysimon/archive/2012/07/25/installing-the-bi-features-of-sharepoint-2013-preview.aspx

One more thing, what sharePoint version you are using StD or enterprise?